# Show that $ 1'x <= r\sqrt{n} $

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that: If  $ ||x||^2 <= r^2 $

Then  $ 1^Tx <= r\sqrt{n} $

$\forall x \in R^n$.

I've tried to show by induction, but I could only (easily) show that $ ||x|| <= (1^Tx) $

And that $ ||x|| <= r\sqrt{n} $,

So my transitive argument is not valid and I can't find another way in.

($ 1^T := (1,1,\dots,1) \in R^{1\times n} $)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Using the Hint above:

$|1^T x| <= ||1||||x|| <= ||1||r = r\sqrt{n} \;\;\;\;\; \blacksquare $

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality!